# Code on clicking javascript function is not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am a beginner in javascript that's why I am unable to understand that what is the problem with my code.

I simply want to add class `.open` to my maindiv on clicking it.  I want my div to open from left side.

```js
function myfunction() {
  $(this).addClass('open');
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

#maindiv {
  margin: 0px;
  transform: rotate(270deg);
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: -292px;
}

.open {
  left: 5px;
  transition-property: left;
  transition-duration: 2s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  transition-delay: 0.5s;
}

#form {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0px;
  transform: rotate(-270deg);
}

#mainbutton {
  width: 303px;
  padding: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js">
</script>
<div id="maindiv" onclick="myfunction()">

  <div id="mainbox">

    <div id="form">
      <h1>main heading</h1>
      <h6>hi</h6>
    </div>

    <button id="mainbutton"> contact me</button>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had problem with `this`. Just try to access your div by ID in jQuery. You may also want to change `.addClass` to `toggleClass` if you want to toggle it on next click.

```js
function myfunction() {
  $("#maindiv").addClass('open');
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

#maindiv {
  margin: 0px;
  transform: rotate(270deg);
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: -292px;
}

.open {
  left: 5px !important;
  transition-property: left;
  transition-duration: 2s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  transition-delay: 0.5s;
}

#form {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0px;
  transform: rotate(-270deg);
}

#mainbutton {
  width: 303px;
  padding: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js">
</script>
<div id="maindiv" onclick="myfunction()">

  <div id="mainbox">

    <div id="form">
      <h1>main heading</h1>
      <h6>hi</h6>
    </div>

    <button id="mainbutton"> contact me</button>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: It does apply class name open to the div. There must be something wrong with your css then

Comment: oh! i am unable to figure out that problem

Comment: `.open {left: 5px !important}` will fix the problem

Comment: I fixed it in snippet, try it out. Works now

Comment: It's ok. Hope you may consider marking my answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

You pass this as paramter for the function. Then it will work.

```
<div id="maindiv" onclick="myfunction(this)">



function myfunction(elm) { $(elm).addClass('open'); }
```